# Que no se mueva canvas al dibujar en movil

Tags: html, css

Tengo un cuadro canvas para dibujar una firma, pero al presionarlo en la versión móvil se mueve toda la pantalla y no deja hacer bien el dibujo, lo estoy haciendo en html, css y bootstrap, quisiera saber si hay alguna manera que el modal quede estatico. O sea que al presionarlo con el dedo deshabilitar todo movimiento

```html
            <div class="modal fade modaldefirma" id="firmaModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="firmaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="firmaModalLabel">Firma</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <canvas id="canvas">Su navegador no soporta canvas </canvas>
                        <p id="limpiar">Borrar</p>
                        <!-- <button class="btn-mfirma" onclick="mandarImagen()">Agregar Firma</button> -->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="mandarImagen()">Agregar Firma</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Esto es demasiado corto como para incluirlo en una respuesta.
Solamente debes hacer uso de los eventos onTouchStart, onTouchMove y onTouchEnd, en el evento onTouchMove desatuva el evento por defecto 

const handleMove = (ev)=>{
    ev.preventDefault()
   //El resto de tu código
}

Answer (score 0):

Puedes desativar el scrol

```js
function noScroll(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0)
  }
  
window.addEventListener('scroll',noScroll)
```

```css
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```